# Return Page Load Time as an alert doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, load

I have to do a little website and i got a javascript on there, which returns the page load time in the console.
Thats works fine. But when i try to do the exact same thing with an alert, it won't work.
My code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
 window.performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || 
{};
 var timing = performance.timing || {};
 var parseTime = timing.loadEventEnd - timing.responseEnd;
 console.log('Ladezeit: ', parseTime, 'ms');
 alert('Sorry for the ', parseTime, 'ms, till the website was completely loaded.')
 }, 0);
});
```

The console.log is working fine, but the alert is only showing up "Sorry for the"
Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Yeah, alert doesn't take multiple arguments.. you need to concatenate the string `'Sorry for the ' + parseTime + 'ms, etc..'`

Comment: Oh wow. I totally forgot that :D Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking the use of `alert`. `console.log` can take an array of parameters, alert just takes one string as an argument.

Concatenate the string to use it in alert:

`'Sorry for the ' + parseTime + 'ms, etc..'`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let alertString= 'Sorry for the ' + parseTime + 'ms, till the website was completely loaded.';
alert(alertString);
```

You are passing in 3 arguments to alert, instead of a string containing your response time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the + symbol to concatenate strings (and variables) in Javascript. 
Try this:

```
alert('Sorry for the ' + parseTime + 'ms, till the website was completely loaded.');
```